# Terminal can't scroll after overnight idle computing

Tags: command-line, scrolling, history, scrollbar

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using ubuntu terminal, running zsh with oh-my-zsh.
I'm on a ssh session to a remote computer with the same configuration.

I launched a big computing and forgot to output the result in a file.
I thought it was no big deal, I would get the result in the terminal.

But this morning, I can't scroll in my terminal. The mouse wheel just browse the history instead of scrolling, and the scroll bar is all screen long, so can't be moved. The search function just search inside the current window, can't go to previous lines.

In an other tab of the same window, I'm not in an ssh session and there is no problem. Of course I tried to disconnect from the ssh session, but it doesn't solve the problem.

This is the second time it's happening, any idea how to get my results back, and how to avoid it to happen?

Comment: Try clicking in the terminal windows and pressing some control, shift, alt, and escape. Then hit return. Does this help?  Or look in the preferences for the terminal and check that you've actually enabled scrollback.  Perhaps whatever you're running is sending crazy control characters to the terminal?

Comment: I had another terminal open as well as an other tab open in the faulty terminal, both of them are working well, so no problem with the terminal preferences I think.

Comment: I tried all sort of keys combinations with no success

Comment: Try pressing escape then i and then try again.

Comment: nope, no change

Comment: echo -e "\033c"    and then  echo -e "\033[?8h"      http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: echo -e "\033c" stopped the bad behavior, I have control of the scrolling again, but all the output is gone, so it's not better than just closing the terminal and opening a new one

Comment: I just lost all my results, didn't I ?

Comment: No, i didn't post the command to reset scrollback (echo -e "\033[3J")

Comment: Still the same as if I had closed the tab and reopened it

Comment: Perhaps you can rerun the command which causes the problem and see if the output contains any odd control characters which are causing the problem.